# Use Photoshop actions on the server

Tags: client-server, remote-access, photoshop-script

I need to use the photoshop action(some kind of macro), which I have already recorded, on the server.

This server is going to have some clients, who are able to send photos to the server.

Server should process the photo(according to the recorded action), then return and save in the db processed photo.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you might find this useful (if you've not seen it already) [photoshop-on-web-server-for-scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753274/photoshop-on-web-server-for-scripts)

Comment: thank's a lot! I have already solved the problem using some tricks & OpenCV=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have used the openCV to solve my problem
Now it is fine)

Comment: Could you elaborate how do you solve your problem using OpenCV? Thanks